# Replace string at particular position In PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have to replace string but it's simple in PHP but my string just like these here i show you.Please any one help me.

```
$string = "#x93F;#x902;#x91C";
```

Above string i want to replace it with

```
 #x91C;#x93F;#x902;
```

But one thing in these string replace. We don't know last word of the $string  `#x91C`;  .

Any word comes in last it's place in to front of that string. How can i solve that please any one help me.

Comment: yes i want semicolon. $string = "#x93F;#x902;#x91C;";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capturing groups to capture the characters you want. Later you could replace the matched characters with the chars inside the group.

**Regex:**

```
^([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);$
```

**Replacement string:**

```
$3;$1;$2;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tE2lR4/3)

```
$string = "#x93F;#x902;#x91C;";
echo preg_replace('~^([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);$~', '$3;$1;$2;', $string);
```

**Output:**

```
#x91C;#x93F;#x902;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:[^;]+;)*)([^;]+)(?=$)
```

Replace by `$2;$1`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/9